# Create a Jenkins Job to run JMeter tests on a remote EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-plugins, remote-access

I have a Java application that creates and runs JMeter tests.
Those tests need to be run on a remote EC2 instance.
Is it possible to have some command in Jenkins (which is on a separate AWS machine) to clone a git project to a remote EC2 instance? And run the flow there?

I will appreciate any thoughts and ideas!

Comment: Is your remote EC2 instance on a fixed machine or it would be dynamic.

Comment: It's on fixed machine for now

Comment: So you can try to use SSH plugin to do this thing. Send the artifact over SSH and execute the artifact on the remote machine.

Comment: thank you @chenrui, I've got it working

Comment: can you post your solution below, that would be helpful for others :)

Answer (score 0):

So, here is my solution:

- in Jenkins in Build section add 'Execute shell' step and do scp there for pom.xml and src folder from the Jenkins workspace to ec2 instance tmp folder
  in my case it looks like this:

scp -i ../../../jobs/utilities/keys/.pem pom.xml ec2-user@ec2-00-000-00.compute.amazonaws.com:/tmp

scp -i ../../../jobs/utilities/keys/.pem -r src ec2-user@ec2-00-000-00.compute.amazonaws.com:/tmp

- then add 'Send files or execute command over SSH' step and in the Exec command section put next:

sudo rm -rf ../../my_project_folder_name/

sudo mkdir ../../my_project_folder_name

cd ../../tmp

sudo cp pom.xml ../my_project_folder_name/

sudo cp -r src ../my_project_folder_name

cd ../my_project_folder_name

sudo mvn clean test

- then add one more 'Execute shell' step to copy all the files from tag=rget folder to be able to use them for different reports:

scp -i ../../../jobs/utilities/keys/.pem -r ec2-user@ec2-00-000-00.compute.amazonaws.com:/my_project_folder_name/target .

That's it :)